# Encadenar dos "not in" en SQL con subconsultas

Tags: sql, select, oracle-sqldeveloper

¡Buenas!
Estoy estudiando SQL y ahora mismo estoy con el tema de consultas. El caso es que me sale un error y no encuentro la solución. El ejercicio es el siguiente:
**Listar todas las plantas de las que no disponemos ejemplares comprados, ni tenemos métodos de reproducción para ella.**
Y me entregan el siguiente esquema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, he usado dos subconsultas para saber la id de todos los ejemplares comprados, por un lado, y la id de todos los casos de la tabla reproducción que tienen métodos. Y a ambas le aplico un where con un not in para sacar la solución. Queda algo así:

```
select * from planta where id_planta 
            not in (select e.id_planta from  ejemplar e join comprado c on (e.id_planta=c.id_planta)) and
            not in (select r.id_planta from reproduccion r join metodo m on(r.id_metodo=m.id_metodo));
```

La primera subconsulta funciona, pero la segunda no, y me marca un error sobre el select sin mucho detalle.

¿Alguien me explica qué he hecho mal, porfa?

Comment: Y que error te da?

Comment: @Japv Me subraya el "select" de la segunda subconsulta como si me hubiera equivocado al escribir la expresión. Al darle a "run", me salta: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: Te falta el campo al que le aplicas el not in, fíjate en la primera sub consulta que pones where campo not in, en la segunda omite ese campo, deberías poner and campo2 not in....

Comment: Vale. Pensaba que no era necesario volver a llamar al campo. Muchas gracias, @Japv

Answer (score 0):

Vale. He probado a fundir las dos subconsultas en una. Aun así, no estoy 100 % seguro de que dé el resultado esperable en todos los casos:

```
select * from planta where id_planta 
        not in (select e.id_planta from  ejemplar e join comprado c on (e.id_planta=c.id_planta)
                    where e.id_planta not in (select r.id_planta from reproduccion r join metodo m on(r.id_metodo=m.id_metodo))
                );
```

Eso sí, sigo sin entender por qué no me dejaba encadenar los dos "not in". ¿Alguien tiene una idea?

Answer (score 0):

Tu consulta se puede solucionar con un par de LEFT JOINS. Usar NOT IN a veces es una mala practica ya que tenes que escanear toda la tabla destino para ver si tu valor esta contenido en ella (te recomiendo leer acerca de TABLE and INDEX SCAN para entender esto)

Una manera de solucionar tu consulta seria

```
SELECT P.*
FROM PLANTA P
LEFT JOIN 
  (EJEMPLAR E INNER JOIN COMPRADO C ON E.ID_PLANTA = C.ID_PLANTA AND 
      E.N_EJEMPLAR = C.N_EJEMPLAR) EC 
ON P.ID_PLANTA = EC.ID_PLANTA
LEFT JOIN REPRODUCCION R ON P.ID_PLANTA = R.ID_PLANTA
WHERE R.ID_PLANTA IS NULL AND E.ID_PLANTA IS NULL
```

Para explicar un poco
En el primer LEFT JOIN obtenemos todos los ejemplares que fueron comprados, ya que estamos joineando por las FK.
El segundo LEFT JOIN es simplemente la tabla REPRODUCCION, fijate que esta tabla es una tabla de relacion, es decir que si la planta no aparece en esta tabla, quiere decir que no existe un metodo tampoco, lo cual satisface tu pregunta.
Por ultimo en el WHERE solo nos quedamos con los registros que no tengan ID_PLANTA de la tabla de REPRODUCCION (No tenemos metodos de reproduccion para ella) y para los que no tengan ID_PLANTA de la tabla EJEMPLARES (No hay ejemplares comprados)

Espero que esto funcione. Lo hice para SQL Server pero si estas trabajando en MYSQL, ORACLE o POSTGRE adaptalo.

Saludos!